# building c# app with cmake on mac

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, cmake

Is it possible to use c# (csharp) in cmake on mac?

With -G"Xcode", I get

> CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/CMakeDetermineCSharpCompiler.cmake:5 (message):
>     C# is currently only supported for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and later.

I have visual studio installed, but it is not listed in the generators.

Comment: The prefered Builder for C# is MsBuild. You can install MsBuild, which is open source (on GitHub) or cake (a maker in C#).

Comment: ok, I have msbuild available. how do I use it with cmake?

Comment: these are generators I get with cmake --help:
  Unix Makefiles,
  Ninja,
  Xcode,
  CodeBlocks - Ninja,
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles,
  CodeLite - Ninja,
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles,
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja,
  Sublime Text 2,
  Kate - Ninja,
  Kate - Unix Makefiles,
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja,
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles